# Proving that a particular Green's function is always positive

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following problem comes from Birkhoff and Rota's text **Ordinary Differential Equations**:

Given the homogeneous differential equation $y'' + q(t)y = 0$ with $q(t) < 0$, show that the associated Green's function $G(t,\tau)$ is positive and concave upward for $t > \tau$.

Here's what I have thus far:  Let $f, g$ be linearly independent solutions of our DE.  Then Green's function is given by

\begin{align}
G(t, \tau) & = \frac{f(\tau)g(t) - g(\tau)f(t)}{W(f,g,\tau)}
\end{align}

where $W(f,g,\tau)$ is the Wronskian of $f(\tau)$ and $g(\tau)$.  We know a couple of things:

1)  $W(f,g,\tau)$ is in fact a non-zero constant.  (This follows easily from Abel's identity and the fact that $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent.)

2)  By the Sturm Comparison Theorem, we know that $f$ and $g$ each have at most one zero.

So what we want to show, I believe, is that for $t > \tau$, $f(\tau)g(t) - g(\tau)f(t)$ has the same sign as the constant $W(f,g,\tau)$.

A nudge in the right direction would be appreciated...